# Calculating while Loop time complexity for the Given code

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

```
def smallestSubWithSum(self, a, n, x):
    min1 = float('inf')
    i = 0
    while (i < n):
        if a[i] > x :
            return 1
        else:
            sum1 = a[i]
            j = i + 1
            
            while (j < n):
                sum1 += a[j]
                
                if sum1 > x:
                    m = j - i + 1
                    min1 = min(m,min1)
                    break
                else:
                    j +=1
            i +=1
    return min1
```

I was solving the question and just thinking that time complexity for the  given code should be O(n^2) since it involved two for loops. but while submitting the code it got accepted under O(n).
can someone explain me this if it O(n) or O(n^2). I know question is beginner level, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: 'while submitting the code it got accepted under O(n)' where did you submit the code; to a professor? This code can be O(n^2) with certain inputs, for example, with an array of all zeros and x = 0.

Comment: No in an online platform.

Comment: input used for the testcase were

Comment: A[] = {1, 4, 45, 6, 0, 19}
x  =  51